# Redis Info Command

Tags: php, redis

Want to know in detail about the purpose of the "info" Command in redis and the detailed description of each value returned by redis "info"

Comment: http://redis.io/commands/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess everyone will come together and put their knowledge in writing and at the end we will have it. A lot of it is self-evident though and as Astha linked there's a little documentaiton too. But, here's a lesser known, at the time of this writing very new and very useful info there. So, since 2.4.6 you have a [list of slaves](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/219) in there, with a format like  `slave0:127.0.0.1,51543,online`. Since 2.4.0 you could get the same information by running the (similarly undocumented but mentioned in the release notes) `CLIENT LIST` command and then checking which client flags contains `S`. The [source](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/2.4.0/src/networking.c#L903) is your best documentation on these flags.

Answer (score 0):

`INFO` command is used to check current statistical information about the instance. You can get all kind of stuff like memory usage, versions of Redis and dependencies, uptime, configuration flags values etc..

At least I, most of the time used this command to check configuration and to check memory usage.

I highly recommend to look at official documentation to get the details: https://redis.io/commands/info

And here is the article I wrote on how to monitor the output of INFO regularly and get notifications: [How to monitor REDIS](https://medium.com/@liesislukas/how-to-monitor-redis-or-anything-else-running-on-your-linux-machine-and-get-an-email-or-trigger-d0d62769f60e)